# Jack compiling taking forever

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-jack-and-jill

After upgrading my project to enable Jack and Java8 features, my 16gb macbook can't seem to build my project anymore.
I see the memory usage getting higher and higher but the process gets stuck at the same point always.

My Gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComBluelinelabsConductor203Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4160Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubJkwiecienEasyImage130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComHannesdorfmannMosbyMvp201Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComHannesdorfmannMosbyMvpConductor082Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComHannesdorfmannMosbyViewstate201Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComHannesdorfmannMosbyViewstateConductor082Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJakewhartonButterknife840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJakewhartonRxbindingRxbinding040Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJakewhartonRxbindingRxbindingAppcompatV7040Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJakewhartonRxbindingRxbindingDesign040Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJakewhartonRxbindingRxbindingRecyclerviewV7040Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJakewhartonRxbindingRxbindingSupportV4040Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJakewhartonTimberTimber431Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComKelvinappsRxfirebase0015Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComSquareupLeakcanaryLeakcanaryAndroid14Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoReactivexRxandroid121Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/leonardo/AndroidStudioProjects/Kluster/app/google-services.json
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:unzipJacocoAgent
:app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithPreJackRuntimeLibrariesForDebug
```

My build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    dexOptions {
        maxProcessCount 2
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    defaultConfig {

        jackOptions {
            enabled = true
        }

        applicationId "com.kluster"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
    compile rootProject.ext.supportV4
    compile rootProject.ext.supportDesign
    compile rootProject.ext.supportAnnotations
    compile rootProject.ext.supportAppCompat
    compile rootProject.ext.supportRecyclerView
    compile rootProject.ext.supportCardview
    compile(rootProject.ext.butterknife)
            {
                exclude group: "com.android.support"
            }
    compile rootProject.ext.conductor

    compile(rootProject.ext.easyImage) {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }

    compile rootProject.ext.glide
    compile rootProject.ext.dagger
    compile rootProject.ext.rxJava
    compile rootProject.ext.rxAndroid
    compile rootProject.ext.mosby
    compile rootProject.ext.mosbyViewState
    compile rootProject.ext.mosbyConductor
    compile rootProject.ext.mosbyViewStateConductor
    compile rootProject.ext.rxBinding
    compile rootProject.ext.rxBindingV4
    compile rootProject.ext.rxBindingV7
    compile rootProject.ext.rxBindingDesign
    compile rootProject.ext.rxBindingRecyclerView
    debugCompile rootProject.ext.leakCanary
    compile rootProject.ext.timber

    compile rootProject.ext.firebaseAuth;
    compile rootProject.ext.googleAuth
    compile rootProject.ext.rxFirebase
    compile rootProject.ext.facebook

    provided rootProject.ext.butterknifeCompiler
    provided rootProject.ext.daggerCompiler
    provided rootProject.ext.javaxAnnotation

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

gradle.properties:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Before using Jack the compiler would build in less than 20s or so, what might be wrong ??
Thanks

Comment: I've just faced the same problem on Windows. With jack build took >2m, without jack it took ~11s

Comment: This sucks, I removed also Jack and it's working... Don't know if I should file a bug or something to Gooogle...

Comment: I studied that Jack has not been released as final version and therefore you must be prepared for any bug.

Comment: Same here, project without Jack takes max 2min to compile, with Jack it takes 10min and far far more ram. The official website does not say anything about it not being a final version.

Comment: Same with my windows 7 64 bits (Intel XEON 3.3Ghz/16Gb), it freezes completely my computer...

Comment: Same problem here on CircleCI

Comment: Guess there is no answer for this issue. Just go back to same old builder, tweak some gradle configs and be happy with it

Comment: Enabling jack options will slow down your build process. If you use jack only for Java 8 language features, you can try with the retrolambda library me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this has been [triaged acknowledged as a "Critical" bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203168) and hopefully the "2.4" Gradle plugin should bring us faster build times :)

Not that this may make a major difference, but try updating the app's `build.gradle` with the following

```
android {
   .
   .
   .


  defaultConfig {

    .
    .
    .
    .
    jackOptions {
            enabled true
            additionalParameters('jack.incremental': 'true')
    }
    .
    .
  }

  dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize '4096m'
  }

  compileOptions {
    incremental true
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the Java Heap Size

```
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
```

With a 16gb MacBook Pro you can even bump it up to `8g`